# Xcode エラーの出ないBunble identifier の記載方法

Tags: xcode

Xcode の Ganelal 画面で Team を自分のアカウントにしたら

> Failed to create provisioning profile.
>   There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.
>
> No profiles for 'swift-Beginners.My-Musick' were found
>   Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'swift-Beginners.My-Musick'.

とエラーがでます

調べてみると Bunble identifier が違う人とかぶっていると出るみたいでかぶらないようにいくら変えてもエラーが出ます

Bunble identifier どう記述すればエラーが消えますか？

Comment: エラーメッセージに解決策がそのまま書いてありますが……

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。この英語はどういう意味なのですか？